# Windows user just for one thing

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Is there a way to create a Windows user that all he can do is open one program? I give one of my computers to someone for a specific purpose only and I can't watch if he's using other things or messing things up.

I have Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very least you should set him up to be a very limited user. Test to make sure his account allows him to do what he needs to do, and lock everything else down. You may also be interested in the kiosk mode questions that deal with locking a computer down so users can only access a single app (such as a web browser).

[Questions about "kiosk mode".](https://superuser.com/search?q=kiosk%20mode)

If you can give details on which app it is you want to lock the user down to, we'll be better able to provide specific answers for that app or configuration.

Comment: I need to lock it down to Warcraft 3 only

Comment: A limited account should work for that. I'm not sure if replacing his shell with the warcraft executable, like some of the kiosk mode suggestions, will be the best idea though. Are there things in particular that you wish to prevent him from getting to?

Comment: I don't want him getting to my personal data.. I got it all under documents and another folder on root C drive. any way to deny access from limited account to there?

Answer (score 0):

You can also whitelist by hash the application that you want to run. Kiosk mode is probably a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

This does cost $59, but if you want a program that you can REALLY lock someone down, and do it easily, try "Fortres 101" (yes, the spelling is correct). You can try it free for a month.

http://www.fortresgrand.com/products/f101/f101_downloads.htm (I do not know why it says "Version 6.5 for Windows 2000", but the platforms correctly says "Windows 7 (32 Bit and 64 Bit)/Vista/XP". Get the top one.).