# Running a PC with Windows 7 as an Appliance

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Completely lock a computer and force it to use a single application](https://superuser.com/questions/345271/completely-lock-a-computer-and-force-it-to-use-a-single-application)

What options are available for running Windows 7 as an appliance and is there an official Microsoft program to get involved in?

I would like to run the computer as a box that boots, displays no bios or boot information, then moves immediately to run one program full-screen without allowing the user to interact. It seems like there should be some base configurations that allow this or a special version of Windows that is configured to minimize extraneous display and control.

Comment: @ekaj The bios information requirement is probably beyond the scope of Windows 7 configuration and require a custom bios. However, I'm hoping to avoid all Windows 7 logos, login, and windows as well. Thinking of it as a toaster is good---if you plugged your PC in a display on the side of the toaster you wouldn't want to have a to login or see icons. You also wouldn't want Windows 7 to stop loading and tell you it needs to check the disk, etc.

Comment: Hm, I know it is possible to bypass the login screen, and the Windows 7 logos can be changed, so if they can be changed, they can be removed as well.. You might just have a blank screen for a while as Windows Does have to load some files, but I'll look into it a bit

Comment: Also, to disable the BIOS screens / popups (if even possible) we will probably need some specs, like your motherboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely lock a computer and force it to use a single application](http://superuser.com/questions/345271/completely-lock-a-computer-and-force-it-to-use-a-single-application) also see http://superuser.com/questions/370080/windows-kiosk-restore-functionality, and http://superuser.com/questions/318269/windows-user-just-for-one-thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Embedded Standard is the appliance version of desktop Windows.  This is what's used on things like ATMs and vending machines.

Or at least, it's what Microsoft *wants* appliances to use.  Plenty of vendors just don't care about all the appliance niceties that you mentioned, and run their programs on top of regular desktop Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Kiosk mode.  Lot's of resources on the web. Here's one that looks promising:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617303/does-windows-7-have-a-kiosk-mode

Keep in mind that Windows has no control over the BIOS. But most machines have a way to disable most bios info.

Answer (score 1):

First: To disable to login screen, follow these steps:

1. Open 'Run' (WinKey + R)
2. Type `control userpasswords2`
3. Find "Users must enter a user name and password to use this
   computer”
4. Uncheck this option and press “OK”
5. Then try it out!

To turn off the splash screen, follow these steps:

1. Open 'Run'
2. Type `msconfig`
3. Click on the 'Boot' tab
4. Check the 'No GUI Boot' tab
5. Optional: Click on the 'Startup Tab' and you can pretty much disable
   everything except firewalls, etc. This will speed up boot time as
   well.
6. Apply and restart.

Kiosk mode might be the best bet for you, but I don't really know much about it.

Lastly, to speed up the OS overall, try [these](http://www.computingunleashed.com/speed-up-windows-7-ultimate-guide-to.html).

Working on the other stuff =p